# Flask and dash together: Working on virtual ENV but not in the server

Tags: ubuntu, flask, plotly-dash, linode

I have an app that runs dash from flask. I made it following the instructions from hackesandslackers [here](https://hackersandslackers.com/plotly-dash-with-flask/)

The app work without any problem in my virtual env.

I am deploying my app with Linode on ubuntu, following the instruction from their website [here](https://www.linode.com/docs/development/python/flask-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu/).

However, when I get to the part [Install and Configure Gunicorn](https://www.linode.com/docs/development/python/flask-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu/#install-and-configure-gunicorn) and run `gunicorn -w 3 PlantPhyto:app` I getting the following error:

```
    from PlantPhyto import create_app
ImportError: cannot import name 'create_app' from partially initialized module 'PlantPhyto' (most likely due to a circular import) (/home/PlantPhyto/__init__.py)
```

Someone have any experience with something like that?

Clarify that I am very new on flask and programming in general.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

ok... this is embarrassing but as I said: I am new in programming stuff.

The problem was that I was calling the initial file `__init__.py`. So that was triggering the problem. I re-named as `wsgi.py` and now is running without problems. I do not know whether is need it to have that specific name, but that is what I did and the problem is solved. xD